# SSRS Join Datasets

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have multiple tables that they have about 2000 records. They are not very heavy but when I use INNER JOIN between them, the result will be about 2GB on file. I want to use the result in SSRS Mobile Report, but it continue showing loading gif in ssrs web portal because the data is in another server (reading result data from data server to SSRS server takes long time).
I can load each table in separate Datasets in SSRS and view data with no problem. But can I join Data of these datasets when creating report or maybe create a dataset that uses other datasets, or even use new connection to cached (offline) data on ssrs server?
(using ssrs 2017)

Comment: Does you user need to see every piece of data, or can you filter it down to something more manageable?

Comment: No it is not possible, we have multiple reports made with these data such as pie chart, data grid, total chart ... . the only thing that we can do is to separate data into multiple datasets to do something like pagination. but the problem is that we will have to create datasets by hand periodically

Comment: It sounds like you may be missing some indexes on the the columns you're joining on.

Comment: @aduguid no it's not the problem. result creates in seconds, but tons of rows that are all correct, makes result large in size so I can't transfer them between servers. (not me, actually ssrs)

Comment: you could write a multi query datasource, that joins your data in code, but you would have to comeup with a syntax for that and deployment of custom data sources is tedious